# How to count percentile of distribution in python

Tags: python, numpy, math, statistics, percentile

Is there any python/numpy function that calculates n-th percentile of given probability distribution?

```py
# Like This
distr = [.2, .6, .2]
do_some_magic(distr, 50)  # 1
distr = [.1, .1, .6, .2]
do_some_magic(distr, 50)  # 2
```

Comment: [`numpy.quantile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html)/[`numpy.percentile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html#numpy.percentile)?

Comment: numpy.quantile is just equivalent of numpy.percentile, but with q in the range[0, 1], i wanted something like numpy.percentile, but for probability distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use scipy's `percentileofscore`.

```
from scipy.stats import percentileofscore

distr = [.2, .6, .2]

print(percentileofscore(distr,50)/100)
```

```
1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try following options**

**NumPy Approach:**

```
import numpy as np


distr = np.array([.2, .6, .2])
percentile = np.percentile(distr, 50)

print(percentile)
```

**Pythonic Approach:**

```
import math


def percentile(data, perc: int):
    size = len(data)
    return sorted(data)[int(math.ceil((size * perc) / 100)) - 1]

distr = [.2, .6, .2]

print(percentile(distr, 50))
```

**Output: 0.2**

Comment: I mean percentile of probability distribution, so in this case ```do_some_magic([.2, .6, .2], 50) == np.percentile([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 50)```

Comment: So what is your expected result or approach?